# Post url seems not been called with spring security

Tags: spring, post, spring-security

My issue is that, when I call the url `http://localhost:8080/site/data/gouv/` with postman with corresponding form data parameters, nothing happens. It seems even the call is not catched by the controller because there is no log.

Postman page

[image]

Here is the controller :

```
package com.mintad.spring.controllers;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.site.common.beans.Gouv;
import com.site.common.service.GouvService;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data")
public class DataController {

    @Autowired
    private GouvService gouvService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/gouvernorate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Gouv> addGouvernorate(@RequestBody Gouv gouv) throws IOException {
        gouvService.addGouv(gouv);
        return new ResponseEntity<Gouv>(gouv, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I've tried to call the url with Jsoup as follows :

```
String base64login = new String(Base64.encode("sof:1".getBytes()));
        Document docs = Jsoup.connect("http://localhost:8080/site/data/gouv/").header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64login).
                data("name", "name").
                data("delegation", "delegation").
                data("district", "district").
                data("postalCode", "postalCode").post();
```

But in vain.

Any help please ? I'm using spring security 4.0.4.RELEASE and Spring 4.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: Fire up your favorite browser and open the Network tab from the developer toolbar. Login with your browser to the site. After login check the exchanges between the browser and the server (headers, cookies, url called etc). Reproduced those exchanges in your code with Jsoup.

Comment: It doesn't work at all. It seems like it doesn't find the url itself. I've got 405 error in Chrome console despite the fact I use POST as method in either the controller and Postman ( Rest testing application on chrome)

Comment: What is the `gouv` variable in the `addGouvernorate` method?

Comment: It's gouvernorate. I have edited the code before pasting it here. I've just corrected the code.

Comment: Does it run if you take off spring-security? If affirmative, please paste your security config; If it does not work even without security, maybe you're sending form-encoded POST data to a @RequestBody annotated method?